# Eclipse Invisible Editor

Tags: eclipse

I have eclipse Juno. I'm not sure how, but my editor in eclipse is now "invisible". By invisible i mean, the editor pane is not in the visible window. I'm not a novice in eclipse and i know you can minimize the editors or maximize a different panel - but this isn't the case. There isn't even a minimize/maximize button on this empty space where the editor should be.

However, the title bar shows the current file that is opened (but in the invisible editor and hence invisible). and my outline sidebar shows the file's outline.

I think this might have happened when splitting editor panes (which i do a lot, love the side by side comparison), and also switching the perspective.

Any ideas on how i can get the editor back in the visible window?

[image]

Above is a screenshot of how it looks. At the time of the screen shot i had just recently clicked a file to open it, and it seems to have opened in the invisible editor.

Comment: A screen capture would make it easier for others to understand what you are seeing.

Comment: Indeed, if i manage to get it again then i'll post it. For now, the solution below works.

Comment: After applying the performance patch I've not seen this one again. I just installed 4.3 and haven't seen it there either.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I've tried all given solutions and none of them solved the problem.
Only using ***Window->New Window*** gave me a new fixed eclipse window.

Comment: This works, and though it's annoying to lose all the current files you might be editing, you don't have to restart eclipse.

Comment: Thank you! This worked also in Eclipse 4.3 64bit (Mac) for me.

Comment: Aargh!.  Yes, this works in Kepler too, where the same problem still exists, and I, too, got there by opening a second editor on a file.  Thanks, Stack Overflow!  Preventing another blown stack.

Comment: After `new window` just close the old one and everything is done.

Comment: 2015 checking & the bug is still here! it can appear after Eclipse misunderstood a split view intent and somehow stacked Editing Windows. Failing to find a way to properly close the background windows generated the issue.

Comment: Wow, never had this bug before. New window solved it. Restarted eclipse didn't help at all.

Comment: Just came across this issue in eclipse mars, this was the only solution I could find that was any help.

Comment: This worked with Kepler, while a full restart wouldn't!

Answer (score 19):

Try *Window* > *Reset Perspective* to get things back to normal.

Comment: Has not worked for me. Editor is completely invisible no matter what I seem to do.

Comment: I just had the problem happen again in 4.3 and this didn't fix it :(

Comment: Reset didn't help me in Eclipse 4.3. Only starting a new window helped.

Comment: Thanxx.. Worked for me with Eclipse Mars 1.

Comment: Thanks much !   Worked for me with Eclipse 4.6.3 (Neon.3).

Answer (score 6):

I minimized sharedArea and after restore it was empty. Editors worked well (open, close, save etc.) but i could not see them. Closing **all** perspectives helped.

Comment: Closing all perspectives helped. < Worked for me, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This happens to me sometimes when I try to split an editor group by dragging an editor tab.  The only solution that worked for me was to close every single perspective in the application toolbar, then `Window -> New Window`.

Comment: Solved my problem on RDz, I had an empty shared area, no window borders, just there, files were opening in other views and I couldn't even move them to the shared area.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this happen occasionally when splitting panes. Restarting Eclipse didn't work for me, nor did resetting the perspective.

The solution I stumbled upon was to give the editor area focus (by clicking in the area where it should be, I suppose) and close files in the invisible editor with Ctrl+W until the editor reappears. You may notice the window title changes to follow the file in the hidden editor.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and simply stopping/restarting Eclipse fixed it.

Comment: Acutally, when this problem happened for me, even a restart didn't help. Though i imagine it could work, i still would want to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the fix, when neither resetting the perspective or restarting eclipse helps:
At the bottom of the File Menu, there is your recent file name that you are trying to get back.  Click on that and it should return.

Answer (score 0):

Start eclipse with:

```
eclipse.exe -repair
```