# When opening java files in Eclipse Juno, the editor seems to be minimised or hidden

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I've installed Eclipse Juno SR1 and switched to my old workspace. When I open a java file in the editor, it seems to be minimized (or hidden). The titlebar shows the current file and the outline displays all methods.

This is much as described in the [Eclipse Invisible Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206348/eclipse-invisible-editor), however, the suggested solution 'Window > Reset Perspective' does not work for me.

Any ideas on how I can get the editor back in the window?

I have the same problem with previous version of Eclipse Juno (not SR1).

Comment: Check the 'Error Log' view for any exceptions, might be related to some plug-in you have installed that's not compatible with Juno

Comment: Had the same problem. "New Editor" from the "Window" menu did not work for me BUT "New Window" did. Suddenly the hidden editor was visible in the new window.

Comment: @endevour That worked for me as well. Why not submit as an answer?

Comment: I got the same behavior today and the "New Window" solution did work. But I think there is still some sort of bug. It seems the editors in the current window have somehow gotten lost. No errors and operations which should target the editors continue to operate as if they believe the editors are working correctly (such as clicking a search reference which would open in a particular editor).

Comment: came here through google, for me resizing the eclipse window brings it back on view. But its just a temp solution, for any new window, i have to resize to get it into view. Will try the suggested reset perspective. I am on Kepler by the way

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse Invisible Editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206348/eclipse-invisible-editor)

Answer (score 49):

"Windows" -> "New Window" seems to bring back the invisible editor view.
Then just close the old one and restart eclipse to make sure it "remembers" the configuration.

Answer (score 6):

Try Window > Reset Perspective to get things back to normal.

Comment: The OP wrote: "the suggested solution 'Window > Reset Perspective' does not work for me."

Comment: That does not work in this case. Its clearly some sort of bug but once it happens Eclipse will simply refuse to show it on a reset.

Answer (score 3):

There are times when the editor or other views starts behaving erratic. For such situations do:
"Windows" -> "New Window". 
Close the old one.

Comment: Good answer. My editor was opening in the "footer", next to "Problems". I've tried opening/closing/resetting perspectives, starting with `-clean` but to no avail. `New Window` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in STS and then it contaminated my regular Eclipse in the same workspace. "New Window" helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to restart eclipse.

Just double-click your file inside the **Package Explorer** view. You will see it's name in the title bar, but it won't appear in the editor:

[image]

Now, just type **Ctrl** + **w** (in case of Windows).

Reopen your file, and it will appear in the editor:

[image]